# CakePhp Multiple Requests

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to save multiple requests. Now I have something like that:

```
if($this->Request->save($tmp)) 
if($this->Request->save($tmp2)){code;}
```

$tmp2 overwrites $tmp. How to save them both? (1 by 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save multiple rows to the same model one by one you need to use

```
$this->model_name->create();
```

before each save, otherwise it will create one and other saves will only update first row (if primary key not included in array you are going to use).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not save request data without specifying a model. You only can save data to a model. So you should use $this->model_name->save($this->request->data) instead of $this->request->save. Request is a handler in cake php.

You should try.

```
$this->model1->save($this->request->data["model1"]);
$this->model2->save($this->request->data["model2"]);
```

Don't forget to share results. If you have made a relation in models then you could use cakephp's saveAll().

Comment: This is "Request". Case sensitive. This is name of a model.